# DML Error trying to save a custom Geolocation field

Tags: apex, geolocation

Have a custom compound geolocation field on standard Event object called '`Event_Location__c`'. I then populate the lat and long attributes of the field - so far so good. Now I try to update the Event record having populated those two attributes and get

```
INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Event: bad field names on insert/update call: Event_Location__longitude__s, Event_Location__latitude__s: [Event_Location__longitude__s, Event_Location__latitude__s]
```

I see also that I cannot update the event record if I reference the Event_Location__c field as it's not able to be set (which I realize is in the docs but hey - will try anything once when panic sets in!)

Any suggestions on how to update the event record with the new geolocation values set? Not much point having a field I cant store data in.

Comment: Can `INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE` be thrown if there's a permissions issue like lack of visibility to the field?

Comment: This error could occur either because of missing FLS for the custom field or incorrect record type set for the record (in case you have more than 1 record type in event object). If you could post the code, it would be easier to identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. No record types, can edit in UI and able to update IF I exclude the geocode field. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so the issue was setting the latitude__s and longitude__s attributes on my object record in javascript and then passing to a controller.  Instead, I passed the lat and lon to server, added to the record there and THEN saved. Worked. Go figure.